# How do I customize my room?

Tags: duck-game

When playing Duck Game online, I've noticed that other players are able to change what their room looks like in the pre-game lobby.

How do I customize what my room looks like?

[image: Customized rooms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Duck Game wiki](http://duckgame.wikia.com/wiki/Room_Decoration):

> The lobby can be edited by accessing the computer in the lobby. After selecting an online profile from the computer, or joining or creating an online multiplayer game, select Edit Room from the computer's menu. The Edit Room menu entry is only present if at least one online game has been completed and points or a decorative toy have been earned.